# Create a single Report from multiple forms

Tags: report, ms-access-2010

I am wondering is it possible to create 1 single report based on multiple forms. I have a reporting system which use a form to collect data form the user. Because the user must enter so much data i have split the form into 15 separate forms( the same way some web forms are split over multiple pages). What i want to do is when the user has completed all 15 forms i then want to generate 1 single report based on all of the 15 forms. Is this possible using the sub-forms function or is adding 15 sub-forms to 1 report just to much. Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. You could create and save a request that selects all you need in your report. Then, you create your report using the request as the source.
2. I often use multiple sub-report in a huge report. I find this easier to apply changes in the future, or reuse those sub-reports in other reports.